# Query to identify contiguous ranges

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to write a query on the below data set to add a new column which has some sort of "period_id_group".

```
contiguous  new_period  row_nr  new_period_starting_id
0           0           1       0
1           1           2       2
1           0           3       0
1           0           4       0
1           1           5       5
1           0           6       0
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
contiguous  new_period  row_nr  new_period_starting_id    period_id_group
0           0           1       0                         0
1           1           2       2                         2
1           0           3       0                         2
1           0           4       0                         2
1           1           5       5                         5
1           0           6       0                         5
```

The logic is that for each 0 value in the `new_period_starting_id`, it has to get the `>0` value from the row above.

So, for `row_nr = 1` since there is no row before it, `period_id_group` is 0.

For `row_nr = 2` since this is a new perid (marked by `new_period = 1`), the `period_id_group` is 2 (the id of this row).

For `row_nr = 3` since it's part of a contiguous range (because `contiguous =  1`), but is not the start of the range, because it's not a new_period (`new_period = 0`), its `period_id_group` should inherit the value from the previous row (which is the start of the contiguous range) - in this case `period_id_group = 2` also.

I've tried multiple versions but couldn't get a good solution for SQL Server 2008R2, since I can't use `LAG()`.

What I have, so far, is a shameful:

```
select *
from #temp2 t1
left join (select distinct new_period_starting_id from #temp2) t2 
    on t1.new_period_starting_id >= t2.new_period_starting_id
where 1 = case 
            when contiguous = 0 
                then 1
            when contiguous = 1 and t2.new_period_starting_id > 0
                then 1
            else 1
        end
order by t1.rn
```

Sample data script:

```
declare @tmp2 table (contiguous int
                   , new_period int
                   , row_nr int
                   , new_period_starting_id int);

insert into @tmp2 values (0, 0, 1, 0)
                        , (1, 1, 2, 2)
                        , (1, 0, 3, 0)
                        , (1, 0, 4, 0)
                        , (1, 1, 5, 5)
                        , (1, 0, 6, 0);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @yatinparab updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
select *
    , case
        when contiguous = 0
            then f1
        when contiguous = 1 and new_periods = 1
            then f1
        when contiguous = 1 and new_periods = 0
            then v
        else NULL
    end [period_group]
from (
    select *
        , (select max(f1) from #temp2 where new_period_starting_id > 0 and rn < t1.rn) [v]
    from #temp2 t1
    ) rs
order by rn
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if I'm understanding you correctly, you just need one additional column.

```
SELECT t1.contiguous, t1.new_period, t1.row_nr, t1.new_period_starting_id,
    (SELECT TOP 1 (new_period_starting_id) 
     FROM YourTable t2
     WHERE t2.row_nr <= t1.row_nr
         AND t2.period_id_group > 0 /* optimization */
     ORDER BY t2.row_nr DESC /* optimization */) AS period_id_group
FROM YourTable t1
```

Comment: This is what I've just done, and I got the answer. Nevertheless, upvoted your answer as well

Comment: Thanks!  I Changed it to "TOP 1" with the ORDER BY to improve efficiency.  MAX would have to query all previous rows, whereas TOP 1 with the ORDER BY queries only a few.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another option for this.

```
select t1.contiguous
    , t1.new_period
    , t1.row_nr
    , t1.new_period_starting_id
    , x.new_period_starting_id
from @tmp2 t1
outer apply
(
    select top 1 *
    from @tmp2 t2
    where (t2.row_nr = 1
        or t2.new_period_starting_id > 0)
        and t1.row_nr >= t2.row_nr
    order by t2.row_nr desc
) x
```